# Pandas dataframe doesnt locate column values, gives NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv("ABC.txt",
names=['timestamp', 'value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4', 'label'])

print(df) //This prints values correctly
```

Now, I am separating features

```
features = ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4']

x = df.loc[:, features].values
print(x) // This prints NaN values
```

printing x

```
[[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
 ...
 [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
 [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]
```

What is wrong with this code? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your code works for me, whats in your .txt file?

Comment: I have values like these 1503510962527.000000 -67.000000 -41.000000 -10.000000 -3.000000 -6.000000 -5.000000 Actually it gives "ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')."